# Error when creating polygons with turf.js from existing GeoJSON polygon rings

Tags: leaflet, geojson, turf, node-js

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4
> or more Positions.

when trying to use `@turf/turf` module:

```
async function selectSubregion(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const subRegion = e.target.value;
        const geoJsonData = await GeoJSON();

        subFilterResults(subRegion);

        if (geojsonLayer) {
            map.removeLayer(geojsonLayer);
        }

        console.log(subRegion);
        console.log(geoJsonData);

        geoJsonData.features.forEach((feature) => {
            console.log(feature.properties.COUNTRY);
        });
        // Find corresponding feature in geojsonData
        const feature = geoJsonData.features
            .filter((feature) => {
                if (feature.geometry.type === 'Polygon') {
                    return feature.geometry.coordinates.every((ring) => ring.length >= 4);
                }

                if (feature.geometry.type === 'MultiPolygon') {
                    return feature.geometry.coordinates.every((polygon) =>
                        polygon.every((ring) => ring.length >= 4)
                    );
                }

                return false;
            })
            .find((feature) => feature.properties.COUNTRY === subRegion);
            // .find((feature) => feature.properties.NAME_EN === subRegion);

        console.log('feature:', feature);

        if (feature) {
            // Highlight the feature on the map
            geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON(feature, {
                style: {
                    color: '#06c',
                    weight: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.3
                }
            }).addTo(map);

            // Remove markers outside the selected region
            allMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
                // Using turf to check if the marker is outside the selected feature
                const point = turf.point([marker.getLatLng().lng, marker.getLatLng().lat]);
                
                const polygon = turf.polygon(feature.geometry.coordinates);

                console.log('point:', point, 'polygon:', polygon);
                if (!turf.booleanPointInPolygon(point.geometry.coordinates, polygon)) {
                    // Remove marker if it's outside
                    map.removeLayer(marker);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: SInce the input data is defective, you'd need to provide it in the Question for resolution.

Comment: updated with link to shp files.

Comment: There is no usage of `turf` in your code. Please add that part.

Comment: I suppose your `World_Countries_Generalized.shp` comes from here: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::world-countries-generalized/about. There's also GeoJSON available for download at this site. Did you try that one?

Comment: For me GeoJSON itself, converted with the online Mapshaper from World_Countries_Generalized.shp and displayed in Leaflet works perfectly well. Where did your try to use `turf`?

Comment: updated question with turf usage

Comment: Even if I download the geojson file instead of shp file i still get the same error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create polygon from selected `feature` coordinates with `turf.polygon` function, you have to take into account that selected feature might be polygon or multipolygon.

You have to check geometry type of the feature and then create either polygon with the `turf.polygon` function or multipolygon with the `turf.multiPolygon` function.

Relevant part of the code would then look something like this:

```
allMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
  const point = turf.point([marker.getLatLng().lng, marker.getLatLng().lat]);
  var polygon;
  if (feature.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon')
    polygon = turf.multiPolygon(feature.geometry.coordinates);
  else {
    polygon = turf.polygon(feature.geometry.coordinates);
  }
  if (!turf.booleanPointInPolygon(point.geometry.coordinates, polygon)) {
    map.removeLayer(marker);
  }
});
```

Comment: it seems the last forEach isn't doing anything with the data. I'm confused.

Comment: That's not true, it displays polygon to console with `console.log('From Polygon', polygon);`. You can of course do with polygons whatever you want to do. Code above is just to show that's it's possible to create polygons with `turf` from your GeoJSON source without any errors.

Comment: I don't understand how this fixes the problem.

Comment: I suppose your problem happens at this statement: `const polygon = turf.polygon(feature.geometry.coordinates);`. If you tell where `feature` is coming from (include more related code in the question), I might be able help you.

Comment: `const features = geoJsonData.features`

Comment: There is one `feature` in the statement, not `features`. Please edit your question and add all relevant code, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: it gets looped over. look at the code. `const features = geoJsonData.features
  .filter((feature)`

Comment: should i be returning or what? The console.log doesn't tell me what to do with `polygon`

Comment: In your question you have two separate block of code. It would be just guessing of how they are put together in your app. Unless you provide complete relevant reproducible code it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I updated the question with full function code. This is the offending line: `const polygon = turf.polygon(feature.geometry.coordinates);` that's where it throws.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

```
            // Remove markers outside the selected region
            allMarkers.forEach((marker, index) => {
                const markerPoint = turf.point([marker.getLatLng().lng, marker.getLatLng().lat]);
                let isInside = false;

                if (feature.geometry.type === 'Polygon') {
                    const regionPolygon = turf.polygon(feature.geometry.coordinates);
                    isInside = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(markerPoint, regionPolygon);
                } else if (feature.geometry.type === 'MultiPolygon') {
                    for (const polygonCoords of feature.geometry.coordinates) {
                        const regionPolygon = turf.polygon(polygonCoords);
                        if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(markerPoint, regionPolygon)) {
                            isInside = true;
                            break; // Break out of the loop if the marker is inside one of the polygons
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!isInside) {
                    map.removeLayer(marker);
                }
            });
```